# Store the result of a query in dynamics365

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm new in dynamics365 programming, I want to store in any variable the result of this query:

the tables are: `InventDim id;  InventTrans it;`

```
while select sum(qty) from it
        where (it.ItemId == "OL-1500") || it.ItemId == "OL-1000"
        join id
        group by inventBatchId
        where id.InventDimId == it.InventDimId
```

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to us a map:

```
Map ret = new Map(Types::String, Types::Real);
MapEnumrator it = ret.getEnumerator();

while select sum(qty) from it
    where it.ItemId == "OL-1500" || it.ItemId == "OL-1000"
    join id
    group by inventBatchId
    where id.InventDimId == it.InventDimId 
{
    ret.insert(id.InventBatchId, it.Qty);
}

while (it.moveNext())
    info(strFmt("%1: %2", it.currentKey(), it.currentValue()));
```

Other options:

- save in a temporary table.
- create a view, use in form
- create a query, use in form

It really depends on how you will use the data.