# Select Sum(NetAmounts) in X++ and display in another Table

Tags: select, sum, axapta, x++

I have created a Table named SalesTable_DNC, in which I stored the fields of a specific Customer Account, retrieving the records from the SalesTable in Dynamics365 passing a specific CustAccount from a Dialog and a button.

Everything works fine, but now I need to make a Select sum of all the NetAmounts related to a specific SalesId of the Customer selected, and store the total amount in another record of my SalesTable_DNC called TotalNetAmount. The NetAmount is in the table SalesLine.

I'm having an issue since I can't find much documentation online and I can't find the right approach to solve this. I was trying to store the result of the Sum by doing:

```
total = select sum(LineAmount) from salesLine where salesLine.SalesId==salesTable_dnc1.SalesId;
```

which is wrong of course.

Can anyone suggest a better approach? Sorry but I'm totally new to X++ and Dynamics, and I'm stuck in this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple case you can use a select expression.

```
total = (select firstonly sum(LineAmount) from SalesLine 
             where SalesLine.SalesId == salesTable_dnc1.SalesId &&
                   SalesLine.SalesStatus != SalesStatus::Canceled).LineAmount;
```

I added the test of cancelled lines as this may otherwise bite you.

[Select expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data/xpp-select-expression) do not support joins.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. After executing the `select sum(LineAmount) from salesLine` you can then use `total = salesLine.LineAmount;` to assign the result to `total`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data/xpp-select-statement#aggregate-functions:

> The aggregate functions perform calculations on a single field over a group of records.
>
> The result is returned in the field that you perform the aggregate function over.

This Q&A describes a similar situation:
[Store the result of a query in dynamics365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857416/store-the-result-of-a-query-in-dynamics365)